# ofVideoPlayer does not work

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I am working on showing sample.mp4 on openframeworks of 0.8.0 / Visual Studio 2012 v110 toolsets / Windows 7.

```
void testApp::setup(){

    myPlayer.loadMovie("sample.mp4");
    myPlayer.play();

}
```

I put sample.mp4 in the src directory, same as where tesApp.cpp is located.  This goes through the build process; however, it crashes with the following output:

```
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\of_v0.8.0_vs_release\apps\myApps - コピー\emptyExample\bin\emptyExample_debug.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\of_v0.8.0_vs_release\apps\myApps - コピー\emptyExample\bin\FreeType-6.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\of_v0.8.0_vs_release\apps\myApps - コピー\emptyExample\bin\Zlib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crtdll.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\of_v0.8.0_vs_release\apps\myApps - コピー\emptyExample\bin\FreeImage.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\of_v0.8.0_vs_release\apps\myApps - コピー\emptyExample\bin\fmodex.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMJP14.IME'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMJP14.IME'
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMJP14.IME'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcr90.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcp90.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMJP14K.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig7icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\IME14\IMEJP\IMJPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\IME14\SHARED\IMJKAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\IME14\IMEJP\IMJPPRED.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\IME14\IMEJP\IMJPTIP.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\IME14\SHARED\IMETIP.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\IME14\SHARED\IMECFM.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'emptyExample_debug.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\IME14\SHARED\IMECMPS.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x3b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1fe0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x13b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2780 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x263c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5724] emptyExample_debug.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This is my question: did I put the sample.mp4 file in the right place?  If so, how can I make this `loadMovie` function work?

Answer (score 2):

`ofVideoPlayer::loadMovie` (like most loading functions in openFrameworks) looks in the "bin/data" directory by default.  Place the movie file there and and your code should work as written.